# SQL find repeated values

Tags: sql

I need to identify rows where a certain value is repeated. Here is a sample table:

```
COUNTRY         CITY
Italy           Milan
Englad          London
USA             New York
Canada          London
USA             Atlanta
```

The query should return...

```
COUNTRY         CITY
Englad          London
Canada          London
```

...because London is repeated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Which SQL server? They all have some differences.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use a subquery that counts the number of times each city appears (and filter to those values that appear more than once):

```
SELECT * FROM Cities
WHERE City in
(
    SELECT City FROM Cities
    GROUP BY City
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select country, city 
from aTable
where city in
(
    select city
    from aTable
    group by city
    HAVING count(1) > 1
)
```

Try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9b1a/1

Or if the same city & country combo appears twice and you're only interested where the countries are different:

```
select distinct country, city 
from aTable
where city in
(
    select city
    from aTable
    group by city
    HAVING count(distinct country) > 1
)
```

Try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dfaa/2

Comment: Thank you all, however I need rows where country is different and city is the same as mentioned in the sample table that i provided before. Your queries return identical rows, where both country and city are the same. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user2832605 To check, is the data in the right columns in your table?  The above code should work (try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9b1a/1).  However if you need it the other way round to what's provided swap the words `city` and `country` in the above code.

Comment: ps. Added second solution based on your answer - i.e. avoiding cases where the city appears twice because the same city & country combo appears twice.

Answer (score 2):

If your DBMS supports windowed aggregates.

```
SELECT COUNTRY,
       CITY
FROM   (SELECT COUNTRY,
               CITY,
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CITY) AS Cnt
        FROM   Cities) T
WHERE  Cnt > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e62c2/1)

Answer (score 0):

This one works. Got it from my wife (she finally had time to look into this). Thought you might be interested.

SELECT * FROM Cities
WHERE City in ( select city
                from (SELECT City, 
                             count(distinct country) 
                      FROM Cities
                      GROUP BY City
                      HAVING count(distinct country)  > 1) a     )

Comment: Ahh - do you have some rows which have the same country and city?  If so you would need the distinct keyword - you can optimise what you've got further by doing the following: `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dfaa/2`